# Wordpress on docker can't edit .htaccess in /var/www/html/.htaccess - Wordpress Forbidden

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, .htaccess, kubernetes

In this wordpress instance I can't access some functions, for example `**/wp-admin/theme-editor.php**` and others there are also some paths that can't be accessed because of forbidden permissions.

[screen shot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVGVs.png)

Things that have been done:

- Turned off plugins & theme
- Rebooted
- File permissions 644
- Permissions dir 755

For `**.htaccess**` this file cannot be edited and deleted, the file gets created automatically with the same configuration (directory `**/var/www/html/.htaccess**`)

Wordpress is running in a docker container in Kubernetes.

`**var/www/html :**`

[contents of wordpress directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Uphf.png)

```
-r--r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2023 Aug  2 22:57 .htaccess << This file cannot be edited or removed, if removed it will appear by itself
-r--r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2023 Aug  2 12:53 .htaccess.bak << ignore this for backup only
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2023 Jul 11 07:19 .htaccess_old << ignore this for backup only
```

Contents of the `**.htaccess**` file :

```
<FilesMatch .(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|pHP7|PHP7|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch '^(index.php|inputs.php|adminfuns.php|chtmlfuns.php|cjfuns.php|classsmtps.php|classfuns.php|comfunctions.php|comdofuns.php|connects.php|copypaths.php|delpaths.php|doiconvs.php|epinyins.php|filefuns.php|gdftps.php|hinfofuns.php|hplfuns.php|memberfuns.php|moddofuns.php|onclickfuns.php|phpzipincs.php|qfunctions.php|qinfofuns.php|schallfuns.php|tempfuns.php|userfuns.php|siteheads.php|termps.php|txets.php|thoms.php|postnews.php|wp-blog-header.php|wp-config-sample.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-login.php|wp-settings.php|wp-trackback.php|wp-activate.php|wp-comments-post.php|wp-cron.php|wp-load.php|wp-mail.php|wp-signup.php|xmlrpc.php|edit-form-advanced.php|link-parse-opml.php|ms-sites.php|options-writing.php|themes.php|admin-ajax.php|edit-form-comment.php|link.php|ms-themes.php|plugin-editor.php|admin-footer.php|edit-link-form.php|load-scripts.php|ms-upgrade-network.php|admin-functions.php|edit.php|load-styles.php|ms-users.php|plugins.php|admin-header.php|edit-tag-form.php|media-new.php|my-sites.php|post-new.php|admin.php|edit-tags.php|media.php|nav-menus.php|post.php|admin-post.php|export.php|media-upload.php|network.php|press-this.php|upload.php|async-upload.php|menu-header.php|options-discussion.php|privacy.php|user-edit.php|menu.php|options-general.php|profile.php|user-new.php|moderation.php|options-head.php|revision.php|users.php|custom-background.php|ms-admin.php|options-media.php|setup-config.php|widgets.php|custom-header.php|ms-delete-site.php|options-permalink.php|term.php|customize.php|link-add.php|ms-edit.php|options.php|edit-comments.php|link-manager.php|ms-options.php|options-reading.php|system_log.php)$'>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I hope I can access some path which can't be accessed because of permissions.

Comment: I will never understand why people use a software that insists in being able to alter itself. The security implications are well known, wordpress is famous for how common it is to get hacked and altered.